# How can I pass a date value from this IF statement to another IF STATEMENT PHP?

Tags: php, date, variables, if-statement

**Scenario:**

If I click button name 'next' it will go to the first `IF` STATEMENT and set date to next 'Y-m'.

If I click button name 'previous' it will go to the second `IF` STATEMENT and set date to previous 'Y-m'.

Inside first `IF` statement have variable `$NextMonthyyyymm` and the value is date. eg: 2015-11

I want this variable (`$NextMonthyyyymm`) pass to the next `IF` statement which is the variable is use to get the previous day.

```
echo $LastMonthyyyymm= date('Y-m', strtotime("-$decrement1 month", strtotime($NextMonthyyyymm)));
```

PHP code:

```
if (isset($_POST['next'])){ 
   $_SESSION['i'] = isset($_SESSION['i']) ? ++$_SESSION['i'] : 1;
   $increment1 = $_SESSION['i'];
   echo $NextMonthyyyymm= date('Y-m', strtotime("+$increment1 month ", strtotime($CurrentMonthyyyymm)));
   }
   else{
   unset($_SESSION['i']);
   }

//settype($getValue, "String");
//$getValue = $NextMonthyyyymm;

if (isset($_POST['previous'])) 
   {
   $_SESSION['d'] = isset($_SESSION['d']) ? ++$_SESSION['d'] : 1;
   $decrement1 = $_SESSION['d'];
   echo $LastMonthyyyymm= date('Y-m', strtotime("-$decrement1 month", strtotime($NextMonthyyyymm)));
   }
   else{
   unset($_SESSION['d']);
   }
```

HTML code:

```
 <button class='fa fa-chevron-circle-left btn-primary btn btn-xs' name="previous" type="submit">Previous</button>
 <button class='fa fa-chevron-circle-right btn-primary btn btn-xs' name="next" type="submit">Next</button>
```

I have try set variable to String to get value (`$NextMonthyyyymm`) from first `IF` STATEMENT and place it between `IF` STATEMENT and then I put the variable inside the second `IF` STATEMENT, but it does not work.

Please, Stack Overflow, don't ban my question and set my account reach to limit to ask a question. I have tried to search existing 'question' that suitable with my problem but do not match :(

Thanks,
Faizal

Comment: Did you declare the `$NextMonthyyyymm` before the first `IF` statement? Or inside the first `IF` statement?

Comment: I already declare it at the top. I just want to know how can the value [$NextMonthyyyymm] inside first [IF] statement pass to the next [IF] statement.

Comment: I guess you can't. Because when you click the `previous`, the first `IF` statement won't run. That's why you have to declare the value at the top, then use it inside both of the `IF`, or you reassign the value to the `$NextMonthyyyymm` in the 2nd `IF`.

Comment: Thanks TJL. I will try that.